# inspect attributes of object python

Tags: python, attributes, inspect

I have an object in python like `<Person at /project/persons/id>`. Now I want to see all the attributes of the person like I have FirstName, LastName and title of the person. What I would like to get is 
`{'FirstName':'Anna', 'LastName': 'Perry', 'Title' : 'Ms.'}`.

I tried `object.__dict__` but it gives me other built-in attributes as well. I would only like to get user specified attributes. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Any reason you're using an object's attributes to store the information, and not actually using a dict contained in the object?

Comment: I'd suggest a property that returns a dict of the relevant info. If you want quick+dirty, subtract object.__dict__ from your object's .__dict__.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to get only the user-defined attributes.  Often people will use dunder names as a signal:

```
attrs = {}
for k in dir(my_object):
    if k.startswith("__") and k.endswith("__"):
        continue
    attrs[k] = my_object[k]
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I have other buit-in attributes that do not start and end with __. What I want to get is only user specified attributes.